# Importing another model into model in ModelBuilder using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I am new to ModelBuilder.
I have been trying to create a toolbox. I have managed to branch down the tool into simple models in ModelBuilder but in most cases I cannot combine my models together. I mean, the models work properly in separate models but I cannot find a way to have them all in one model. Sometimes it is impossible to join them together and sometimes it doesn't work properly. I was wondering what is the best way to combine them together.

Should I convert all the models to script and then combine them together and use the tool as a script or there is a  way to export/import the models?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible. To get started you should read up on the [Integrating a Model within a Model](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Integrating_a_model_within_a_model/002w0000007p000000/)  help page within [ArcGIS Resource Center](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_ModelBuilder/002w00000001000000/)